# Spring Security always redirect to authentication-failure-url

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

recently i have use Spring Security for my Spring MVC Web Admin. I Have a trouble when using Spring Security. When login process, always redirect to authentication-failure-url. I have my own UserDetailsServiceImpl that implements UserDetailsService (from Spring Security Feature).

This is my spring security

```
<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/error" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/index"
        always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/error"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE"
        logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true" />
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->

    <!-- csrf /-->

</http>

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="com.mezzo.security.AuthenticationSuccessListener">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/index" />
    <!-- After login, return to the last visited page -->
    <beans:property name="useReferer" value="true" />

</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
    class="com.mezzo.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Please, what's the problem with my security config xml.
Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Check if "userDetailsService" bean is able to  load the input user successfully and have any granted authorities. If its not able to load the user, then it will be an authentication failure.

Comment: Hi @RahulVedpathak, thanks for your comments.
I have check in the UserDetailsServiceImpl class, i try debug and successfully load user info and authorities (until return statement), but i don't know where is the bug. Every thing seems to be ok in UserDetailsServiceImpl class.